# Django model save() method overriding cause ValueError

Tags: python, django

I try to override save() method for my Article model. I did same thing few times and it was OK. But, for this time Value Error Raised.

My class:

```
 class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url = self.title
        self.url.lower()
        self.url.replace(' ', '_')
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Error log:

```
    >>> a = Article("Title 1", "text")
    >>> a.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/django/project/apps/articles/models.py", line 19, in save
    super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 710, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  ...

  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/dj18/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 985, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Title 1'
```

Comment: Give the model descprtion and specify how you create the object `a` for better clarity

Comment: Is it an Integer field and you are passing a string Object?

Comment: Try to pass the object to a simple model form to see the error list

Comment: model description added, object created with shell

Comment: Note that `self.url.lower()` and `self.url.replace(' ', '_')` do not do what you expect them to do. In a console, try `x = "ABC"; x.lower(); print(x)`.

Comment: Changed to x = x.lower(), tnx

Comment: also found **slugify()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the objects in not the recomended method. You must be [specifiying the parameter names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects) when assigning the values as

```
a = Article(title  = "Title 1",  body = "text")
a.save()
```

Here I have specified that title of the new object must be set to `Title 1`,

And `body` will be set to `text`